# Mobx. parent component is not re-rendered?

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-state-tree

I'm learning mobx. I can not understand why the parent component is not re-rendered. When the button is clicked, the value of the field in the observed object changes. The parent component is an observer. Why isn't it updated?
I made two versions: just mobx and mobx - state - tree. None work.

Mobx

```
import React, { useContext , createContext} from 'react'
import { observer} from 'mobx-react-lite';
import { observable } from 'mobx'


const TestOb = observable({
    Name: 'Test'    
});

const StoreContext = createContext(TestOb);

const ChildComp = () => {
    const store = useContext(StoreContext)
    const clickHandle = () => {     
        store.Name = "Test 2";       
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={clickHandle}>Click</button>
        </div>
    )
}

 const Test = () => {

    console.log("Test comp"); // does not fire on change
    
    return (
        <StoreContext.Provider value={TestOb}>
            <div>
                <ChildComp />
            </div>
        </StoreContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default observer(Test);
```

mobx-state-tree

```
import React, { useContext, createContext } from 'react'
import { observer, types } from 'mobx-react-lite';
import { observable } from 'mobx'
import { types } from 'mobx-state-tree'


const TestStore = observable(types.model({
    Name: types.maybe(types.string)
}).actions(self => {
    return {
        setName: () => { self.Name = "Test" }
    }
}))
const store = TestStore.create({});

const StoreContext = createContext(store);


const ChildComp = () => {
    const store = useContext(StoreContext)
    
    const clickHandle = () => {
        store.setName();
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={clickHandle}>Click</button>
        </div>
    )
}

const Test = () => {
    console.log("Test"); // does not fire on change
    return (
        <StoreContext.Provider value={TestOb}>
            <div>
                <ChildComp />
            </div>
        </StoreContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default observer(Test);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `observer` component will re-render when observable data it depends on changes.

Your `Test` component is currently not dereferencing any observable data. You could try to use `TestOb.Name` to see it working.

**Example**

```js
const Test = () => {
  console.log("Test comp");

  return (
    <StoreContext.Provider value={TestOb}>
      <div>
        {TestOb.Name}
        <ChildComp />
      </div>
    </StoreContext.Provider>
  );
};
```